# On YouTube, is using services like Windows 10 and other applications being Copyrighted?

Tags: copyright, youtube

So I am starting out on YouTube and wondering about copyright. If I post a video on YouTube about fixing Windows 10 or Something to do with that, can that be copyrighted?

Comment: "Can that be copyrighted", can you clarify what you mean by "that"? That you retain copyright on the video? That the video is infringing? Something else?

Comment: Can I be copyrighted by Microsoft if I use there product(WINDOWS 10)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you produce a creative work and fix it in a tangible medium, which you do if you make a video and post it to YouTube, it is automatically protected by copyright. There is nothing special you need to do to copyright it. Note that by posting it to YouTube, you are granting YouTube a very broad license to copy and distribute the video.